# ASP.NET Core Web API - how to consume third-party API based on condition

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I am given a third party API to consume in my ASP.NET Core-6 Web API.

API:

```
"https://api.thirdpartycompany.com:2233/api/BranchDetail"
```

In appsettings.json I have:

```
"Endpoints": {
  "branchUrl": "https://api.thirdpartycompany.com:2233/api/BranchDetail"
}
```

API:

```
{
    "Branches": [
        {
            "BranchName": "Accra",
            "BranchNumber": 1,
            "BranchType": "Human Resource Agency",
            "Country": "Ghana"
        },
        {
            "BranchName": "Kumasi",
            "BranchNumber": 2,
            "BranchType": "Production",
            "Country": "Ghana"
        },
        ...
}
```

The core is as shown below:

Entity:

```
public class Branch
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string BranchName { get; set; }
    public string BranchType { get; set; }
    public int BranchNumber { get; set; }
}
```

DTO:

```
public class BranchCreateUpdateDto
{
    public string BranchName { get; set; }
    public string BranchType { get; set; }
    public int BranchNumber { get; set; }
}

public class BranchResponse
{
    public List<BranchCreateUpdateDto> Branches
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

BaseResponse:

```
public class BaseResponse
{
    public bool Success { get; set; } = true;
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

Service:

Interface:

```
Task<BaseResponse> CreateBranchAsync();
```

Implementation:

```
public class AdminBranchService : IAdminBranchService
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _dbContext;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    private readonly IConfiguration _config;
    private readonly HttpClient _myClient;
    public AdminBranchService(
        ApplicationDbContext dbContext,
        IUnitOfWork unitOfWork,
        ILogger logger,
        IMapper mapper,
        IConfiguration config,
        HttpClient myClient
        )
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
        _mapper = mapper;
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        _logger = logger;
        _config = config;
        _myClient = myClient;
    }
    public async Task<BaseResponse> CreateBranchAsync()
    {
        var branchResponse = new BaseResponse();
        var branches = new List<Branch>();
        try
        {
            string branchUrl = _config.GetSection("Endpoints").GetValue<string>("branchUrl");
            _myClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            _myClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            HttpResponseMessage response = _myClient.GetAsync(branchUrl).Result;

            var stringResult = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            BranchResponse list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BranchResponse>(stringResult);
            foreach (var singleBranch in list.Branches)
            {
                Branch res = new Branch();
                if (_dbContext.Branches.Any(x => x.BranchName == singleBranch.BranchName))
                {
                    res.BranchNumber = singleBranch.BranchNumber;
                    _unitOfWork.Branches.Update(res);
                }
                else
                {
                    //set all fields here
                    res.BranchName = singleBranch.BranchName;
                    res.BranchNumber = singleBranch.BranchNumber;
                    await _unitOfWork.Branches.InsertAsync(res);
                }
                await _unitOfWork.Save();
            }              
            _logger.Information("Branches Added Successfully");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.Error("An Error occured " + ex.ToString());
        }
        return branchResponse;
    }
}
```

As stated earlier, I am consuming a third party API, but I don't want to get all the data.

From

```
BranchResponse list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BranchResponse>(stringResult);
```

I want to get or deserialize only the data where BranchType contains "Human Resource" or "Production"

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Hi @Ayobamilaye, I think it is better to deserialize to model and then filter the model data where BranchType Contains "Human Resource" or "Production". Besides, you model design is not correct. You can see that your json data contains `Country` key but your model does not contain such property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter the list of branches using LINQ once they're deserialized, like so:

```cs
List<BranchCreateUpdateDto> branches;
var filtered = branches.Where(x => x.BranchType.StartsWith("Human Resource"));
```

The AdminBranchService might look like this (I also changed the async calls to be properly awaited):

```cs
public class AdminBranchService : IAdminBranchService
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _dbContext;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    private readonly IConfiguration _config;
    private readonly HttpClient _myClient;

    public AdminBranchService(
        ApplicationDbContext dbContext, 
        IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, 
        ILogger logger, 
        IMapper mapper, 
        IConfiguration config, 
        HttpClient myClient)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
        _mapper = mapper;
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        _logger = logger;
        _config = config;
        _myClient = myClient;
    }

    public async Task<BaseResponse> CreateBranchAsync()
    {
        var branchResponse = new BaseResponse();
        var branches = new List<Branch>();

        try
        {
            string branchUrl = _config.GetSection("Endpoints").GetValue<string>("branchUrl");

            _myClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            _myClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            HttpResponseMessage response = await _myClient.GetAsync(branchUrl);
            var stringResult = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            BranchResponse list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BranchResponse>(stringResult);

            // filter branches based on BranchType
            var filteredBranches = list.Branches
                .Where(x => x.BranchType.StartsWith("Human Resource")
                    || x.BranchType.StartsWith("Production"));

            foreach (var singleBranch in filteredBranches)
            {
                Branch res = new Branch();

                if (_dbContext.Branches.Any(x => x.BranchName == singleBranch.BranchName))
                {
                    res.BranchNumber = singleBranch.BranchNumber;
                    _unitOfWork.Branches.Update(res);
                }
                else
                {
                    //set all fields here
                    res.BranchName = singleBranch.BranchName;
                    res.BranchNumber = singleBranch.BranchNumber;
                    await _unitOfWork.Branches.InsertAsync(res);
                }
                await _unitOfWork.Save();
            }              

            _logger.Information("Branches Added Successfully");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.Error("An Error occured " + ex.ToString());
        }

        return branchResponse;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you can add a middleware to check for the response and filter that out.